# How to add date picker in yii forms?

Tags: php, yii, datepicker

I'm try to add a date picker to my ActiveForm.

```
<?=$form->field($model, 'date_of_birth')?>
```

I also try this way

```
<?=$form->field($model,'date_of_birth')->widget(DatePicker::className()?>
```

It gives me the error: `yii\jui\DatePicker not found`.
At the top of my code, I include `use yii\jui\DatePicker;` but its not work.

Please help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have missed ) in your code, but i don't think that's your error can you try using second parameter as empty array

```
widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::classname(), []);
```

You can also use

```
use kartik\widgets\DatePicker;
```

for date picker http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/datepicker

Answer (score 3):

Here is how you can use it with some useful options:

```
  <?= $form->field($model, 'date_of_birth')->widget(\yii\jui\DatePicker::className(),
    [ 'dateFormat' => 'php:m/d/Y',
      'clientOptions' => [
        'changeYear' => true,
        'changeMonth' => true,
        'yearRange' => '-50:-12',
        'altFormat' => 'yy-mm-dd',
      ]],['placeholder' => 'mm/dd/yyyy'])
    ->textInput(['placeholder' => \Yii::t('app', 'mm/dd/yyyy')]) ;?>
```

Here you can setup format of date in view and also range and how you want to pass it via POST request